# How to route between two internal Angular applications?

Tags: angular

I have built two separate Angular applications. Now, I am trying to integrate them in one Angular project.
Here's the project structure:
[image]

> src : app1 files
>   gestionDeRisque : app2 files

This is Angular.json: 
[image]

As you may have guessed, app1 is configured inside my-app and app2 is configured inside my-app-two.
The only way to switch between the two apps now is to write my-app or my-app-two inside the "defaultProject" property and run the project with ng serve.
However, what I would like is switch between the two apps using html links.
I.e:

> localhost:4000/app1 to serve app1
>    localhost:4000/app2 to serve app2

I couldn't find a way to do this since apparently it contradicts Angular's SPA principle?
So here is my question:
Is it possible to reach the goal I described?
If not, what do you suggest?
Thank you!

Comment: no, it is not possible to add two project. I suggest you to merge two application into single project and separate by different routing url.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do :"merge two application into single project and separate by different routing url"

Comment: then your code should be inside app folder. move you both application inside app folder,

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to create a new module, put your 2 project there and create all dependencies?